# Как мне переработать запрос получив SUM рейтинга всех записей нужной категории из таблицы рейтинга, группировать по object_author?

Tags: mysql

нужно получить самого рейтингового автора по его записям

```
//Если строим ТОП за все время, то берем из таблицы rating_totals
    if ($atts['day'] == 'all') {

        $top_objects = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT object_id, object_author, SUM(rating_total) as total_rating 
        FROM " . RCL_PREF . "rating_totals
        $WHERE
        GROUP BY object_id
        ORDER BY total_rating DESC, object_id
        $LIMIT
        $OFFSET
        ", ARRAY_A);

        $total_post = $wpdb->get_var("
        SELECT COUNT(object_id)
        FROM " . RCL_PREF . "rating_totals
        $WHERE
        ");
    } else {

//запрос в базу
        $top_objects = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT object_id, object_author, SUM(rating_value) as total_rating
        FROM " . RCL_PREF . "rating_values
        $WHERE
        GROUP BY object_id
        ORDER BY total_rating DESC, object_id
        $LIMIT
        $OFFSET
        ", ARRAY_A);

        $total_post = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT object_id
        FROM " . RCL_PREF . "rating_values
        $WHERE
        GROUP BY object_id
        ");
        $total_post = count($total_post);
    }
```

Comment: Собственно заменить group by на требуемый

Comment: на на object_author и все?

Comment: тут же одной записи рейтинг вычисляется и как получить самого рейтингового автора дальше?

Comment: ну да. и object_id убрать после слова select, подозреваю их может быть несколько для одного object_author

Comment: не вижу где бы тут была одна запись. sql запрос с group by возвращает много записей, по одной для каждого уникального значения колонок в нем указанных

Comment: $total_post лишний или нет?

Comment: а ORDER BY total_rating DESC, object_id   тут тоже поменять на object_author ?

Comment: видимо стоит поменять. все таки зависит от желаемого порядка сортировки. Откуда мне знать лишний $total_post или нет. Вы не показали участков кода который бы использовал переменные из приведенного куска

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь вы так нашли лучшие записи по всему сайту и по ним автора ,а надо в рубрике wordpress

Comment: в SELECT не надо добавить wp_terms = "наша категория" ?

Comment: или в WHERE не надо добавить wp_terms = "наша категория" ?